# eclipse java; red warnings in package explorer for ALL projects disappeared; why?

Tags: java, eclipse, error-suppression

Have been using eclipse for java several years; suddenly I cannot find where errors are in projects because the red warnings do not show in package explorer. Please advise. Project file seems in order.

Solved. Missing jar file on build path.

Comment: Window->Show View -> Markers  is this the tab you are looking for in eclipse IDE?

Comment: Thanks but no. Quite recently if I introduce an error into the source file I am editing, a red marker shows  on the line number, but it no longer shows against the file in package explorer, so I cannot  easily find errors I have created in other files by editing the current file. Weirdly, the compiler has also started processing lines I have commented out! This is even more recent. I am not sure what I have done to create this situation.

Comment: ok..Looks like reinstalling eclipse is the only option then.

Comment: I have just realised what causes it, although no idea why. I had inadvertently deleted a jar file from the workspace but left it on the build path list! ) it was off screen so I did not notice) When I removed it from the build path, all the strange behaviour disappeared. Thanks.